# How can we calculate vertical grand totals in pivot table?

Tags: obiee

I am trying to add grand total at the end of each row to the right of a pivot table in an analysis. I can add grand total on the bottom but the rerquiremnt is asking for both the grand totals on the bottom of the pivot and at the end of each row to the right of a pivot table.. any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at how the pivot is constructed you will see that there are sum options for both columns and rows. Just click it.

Comment: I look at the columns and rows and all I can see is the sum for after or before. for the columns its not giving  me the sum across a row like I want.  any specific place that I should look at?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/bCUuqAR.png

Not sure what's "missing" for you as horizontal ans well as vertical totals are just one click

Comment: It appears that you are using an older version , mine doesn't have the option that you screenshot is showing.

Comment: "an older version"?! What are you using.

Comment: I am using BICS

Comment: BICS is older than pretty much anything running on-prem or in-cloud nowadays. It's not even being sold anymore.